# SPUrl broken in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm upgrading from SharePoint 2007 to 2010 and the `$SPUrl:~sitecollection` expression doesn't appear to be working anymore. It replaces `~sitecollection` with the current site URL instead of the root URL. For example, if I'm in `http://mysite.com/its/itsinternal`, and I have a reference to `<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/its %>`, the URL is formatted as `http://mysite.com/its/itsinternal/its`. Is there a configuration somewhere that controls this?

Answer (score 0):

Is /its/itsinternal a site collection with a managed path? I only ask as I'm using ~sitecollection a lot with no issues at all.